# css files not getting cached

Tags: http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control, etag

We are using IBM HTTP server as our web server. Whenever a request is sent to homepage, browser is caching all static files like js or images except CSS.

Why is it caching JS files which are also static but not CSS?

**Below are the request and response headers for CSS**:

```
Status Code:200 OK

**Request Headersview**

Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
DNT:1
If-Modified-Since:Thu, 14 Feb 2013 20:38:02 GMT
If-None-Match:"6b01-4d5b53c299e80"
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.3 Safari/537.31

**Response Headersview**

Accept-Ranges:bytes
Age:0
Cache-Control:max-age=172800
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:5831
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Tue, 26 Feb 2013 23:50:59 GMT
ETag:"6b01-4d5b53c299e80"
Expires:Thu, 28 Feb 2013 23:50:59 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 14 Feb 2013 20:38:02 GMT
Proxy-Connection:Keep-Alive
Server:IBM_HTTP_Server
Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Via:1.1 localhost.localdomain
```

**And these are headers for JS files which are returning 304**:

```
**Request Headersview**

Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
DNT:1
If-Modified-Since:Thu, 14 Feb 2013 20:38:10 GMT
If-None-Match:"7bcc-4d5b53ca3b080"
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.3 Safari/537.31

**Response Headersview**

Cache-Control:max-age=172800
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Tue, 26 Feb 2013 23:50:58 GMT
Etag:"7bcc-4d5b53ca3b080"
Expires:Thu, 28 Feb 2013 23:50:59 GMT
Proxy-Connection:Keep-Alive
Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Via:1.1 localhost.localdomain
```